# javascript function not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have written a small program whilst learning javascript to try and have the user pick two matching cards.  The program works fine in Safari and Explorer (current versions) but will not work in Chrome or Firefox.  I have provided a stripped down version here.  In Safari you click on the displayed image and it runs the function and loads the image, you then select the next image to see if it is a match.  In Chrome if you click the image nothing happens.  In this version I have copied here the click will just display the image in Safari.  I cannot fathom out why Chrome & firefox wont run it?  PS I am very new to learning javascript and do not have knowledge of jquery or anything else other than javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Match the Cards</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css" type="text/css" />
<script>
var turns = 0;
var firstcard;
var secondcard;
var backcard ="images/blueback.png";
var faces = new Array(
"images/kh.png", "images/ks.png");

function ChooseCard(card) {
if (turns == 2) {
return;
}if (turns == 0) {
firstcard = card;
document.images(card).src = faces[card];
turns = 1;
} else {
secondcard = card;
document.images(card).src = faces[card];
turns = 2;
}
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td><img id="image_point" onclick="ChooseCard(0);" src="images/blueback.png" /></td>
<td><img id="image_point" onclick="ChooseCard(1);" src="images/blueback.png" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the console say?https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: Also it might be a better idea to put this in a jsfiddle to see in action

Comment: WHAT DOES THE CONSOLE SAY? "YERP YERP YERP YERP YERP YA YERP!" WHAT DOES THE CONSOLE SAY?? "RAT TAT TAT TAT TAT TA TAT!!"

Comment: @AlienWebguy I hate you so much XD

Answer (score 4):

[`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.images) is an array(-like object, a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) to be precise), not a function. `()` is used to call a function, while `[]` is used to access properties on objects (including arrays).

So you should write:

```
document.images[card].src = faces[card];
```

or even use the `item` method (which is a function) on the NodeList:

```
document.images.item(card).src = faces[card];
```

If you do it one of these ways, it will work in Safari and IE too, because this is the standard way.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8fzc5/) (images won't show up, but it works now)

---

Actually, if you look at your [browser console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), it will tell you that `images` is not a function with a nice message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'images' of object `#<HTMLDocument>` is not
>   a function

---

Note: I understand you are a beginner, but you *really should* read up on **indentation**, and why it is very important. Actually, you should never show unindented to code to other people (including your future self).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
document.images[card].src
```

instead of

```
document.images(card).src
```

`document.images` is an array so you need to use `[index]` to access individual array items.